# Git - retroactively patching a file that will be copied

Tags: git, copy, patch

Suppose I have a git repos that contains `original.script`.  At some point, I want to do something similar to `original.script`, so I decide to use it as a starting point for a new script `modified.script`:

```
% git branch before-cp
% cp original.script modified.script
% git add modified.script
% git commit -m "creating a copy to modify"
% vim modified.script #...
% git add modified.script
% git commit -m "made some modifications"
```

Now, at some point, I discover a bug in `original.script`.  I can just patch `original.script`, but that doesn't help `modified.script` which may retain the bug.  I'd like to fix `original.script` back before it was copied, doing something like:

```
% git checkout before-cp
% vim original.script #...
% git add original.script
% git commit -m "fixing a bug in original before I start copying it"
% git checkout master
% git rebase before-cp
```

But this doesn't work the way I want it to.  The rebased "creating a copy to modify" commit still contains a copy of `modified.script` that's identical to the unpatched version of `original.script` (from `before-cp^`).

I'm ok with my first attempt being the wrong way to do it - but is there a right way to do it?  To retroactively patch a file so that future copies copy the patched version?  Or am I going to have to manually patch `modified.script` (and any other files in the copy-subtree of `original.script`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to manually patch `modified.script`. When you copied `original.script` to `modified.script`, the new commit simply records the fact that you created  `modified.script` with a particular set of file contents. When looking at the diffstat, git will tell you that you copied `original.script` to create `modified.script` but it *inferred* that, the commit itself didn't actually record that fact. If you retroactively modify `original.script` and try to rebase your commit that creates `modified.script` on top of that, it will re-create the *exact same* `modified.script` that you had before, and if you diffstat the commit, it will look like you copied `original.script` and then made some changes (effectively reverting your fix) before actually committing it.

The only solution you have is to apply the same patch to `modified.script`.